# How can i set the alarm on the particular date in android?

Tags: android

Explanation:
           I have calendar in which i set the events on the particular day of the given month.The event is stored into the database. on the event day is occurs it is trigger an alarm to notice the user.

suppose, my event is save on the 29/05/2016 then my alarm is triggered on the particular date.

Notice:i have multiple event created on the particular month.e.g. on the 29th may or 30th may also.

MyQuestion is how can i fire the multiple alarm on the particular multiple days.

Please, understand the flow what i exactly want?

Comment: Please share the code you have written for this flow

Comment: Refers this link which i post today morning.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37475398/how-can-i-call-my-alarm-at-the-time-of-event-occurs-in-android?noredirect=1#comment62448981_37475398

Comment: Also refers https://github.com/SundeepK/CompactCalendarView

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562757/alarmmanager-android-every-day

Comment: @Milan Gajera search alarm manager, you will have an idea.

Comment: hello @NaveenTamrakar see my today morning post on stackoverflow.then tell me where i put the code.

Comment: I referred everything but i don't know how to do that? please help me

Comment: anybody refer the link which i post today morning?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to play alarm for particular date and time , following code may help you

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,5);
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,2012);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,11);

cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,16);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,10);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

Intent _myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ReceiverClass.class);
PendingIntent _myPendingIntent =      
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 123, _myIntent,   
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT|  Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
AlarmManager myAlarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
//myAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() +   (10 * 1000), _myPendingIntent);
myAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),  _myPendingIntent);
```

Comment: Are you refer my post on stackoverflow if not please refer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37475398/how-can-i-call-my-alarm-at-the-time-of-event-occurs-in-android/37475561#37475561

Answer (score -1):

```
 calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,date.getYear());
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,date.getMonth()+1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,date.getDate());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,time.getHours());
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,time.getMinutes());
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,time.getSeconds());
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReciever.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("ReminderDetails",reminderDetails);

        myIntent.putExtra("requestCode", requestCode);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, (int) (requestCode), myIntent,0);
            alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTime(),
                    interval, pendingIntent);
```

The following code here is good live for setting a calender time at the specified time and date.
And the most important thing here stands is that what do you pass in 2nd argument in **alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(_)** method,which is 
**date.getTime()**, which is the only thing will work instead of using 
**calendar.getTimeinMillis()** method, because that will return some unexpected time to be launched for intents.